# How to save the data to local system in electron main window

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to store and write the data to the local system file which is entered in the text box given in the electron window

Is it possible to achieve this using the electron App ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using the standard node.JS filesystem API:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var content = "sample text file content";
fs.writeFile("/folder/filename.txt", content, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("File succesfully saved to disk.");
});
```

The Node Filesystem API can be a bit overwhelming, you could check out helper packages like [fs-jetpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-jetpack), which offer some user-friendly abstractions.

Additionally, the Electron API offers a method called [dialog.showSaveDialog](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) to determine the filepath using a dialog window.

Comment: While performing the operation with the above given code snippet getting the below mentioned error in the console ...                                                 Uncaught Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Comment: Are you attempting to use fs in your renderer process?

Comment: Didn't used any renderer process, fs has been used in seperate html file rather than the main.js file

Comment: The fs module is part of the nodeJS library and therefore unavailable inside your browserWindow. You will have to reference fs as well as your save/load functions in your main.js and reference them via the Electron inter-process communication interface ([Read more about that here](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/))